# Ruby on Rails relation does not exist

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails

Я создаю модель с помощью генератора.

```
rails g model Project name:string
```

После чего выполняю миграцию.

```
rails db:create
rails db:migrate
```

И пытаюсь использовать `

```
project = Project.create({name: 'Project 1'})
```

Получаю ошибку

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "projects" does not exist
```

Подскажите, что я мог не учесть или не настроить, и в каком направлении копать.

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что в базе данных отсутствует таблица projects. Или миграция не прошла, или вы поменяли настройки БД в проекте , а потом не запустили миграции...

Comment: Миграция при этом не выдала никаких ошибок? А в schema.rb есть таблица `projects`?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно задать модель в множественном числе, тогда ошибки не будет

`rails g model Projects name:string
rails db:migrate`